# Control color or font weight of text inside a Pandas dataframe cell exported to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I use Pandas for data analysis and want to produce a spreadsheet where cells have text with different color or with different font weight, for example: "*this is bold and important*, this is not". In a terminal, I can add these control characters before text and change the color and weight of the text after:

```
BOLD  = "\033[;1m"
BLUE  = "\033[1;34m"
CYAN  = "\033[1;36m"
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
```

and go back to normal with:

```
RESET = "\033[0;0m"
```

I know I can [color cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299509/coloring-cells-in-excel-with-pandas) and control the style of a whole cell, but I would like to control font inside a cell.

Is that possible?

Comment: IMO, use `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter` directly here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the font-size of text in dataframe using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284208/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-text-in-dataframe-using-pandas)

Comment: @Laurent I read that thread and it sets the style for a cell or the whole dataframe, when I need to set it inside a cell, e.g. "something innocuous, __something relevant__".